# How to force Robot Framework Script return successfully from the shell with "exit 0"

Tags: robotframework

When using Jenkin plugin for Robot Framework, the instruction stated that we need to force robot framework script return successfully from the shell with "exit 0". This is not a very clear statement.

Can someone tell me how we force the robot framework to return with "exit 0" when tests are successful? An example will be very helpful.

Here is the statement in the Jenkins wiki.

> Force your Robot script to return successfully from shell with "exit 0" to empower the plugin in deciding if the build is success/failure
> (by default Robot exits with error code when there are any failed
> tests)

Answer (score 14):

In order to tell if a job succeeded or failed, jenkins uses the exit code of the last command that was run. "exiting 0" means to have whatever script runs your test finish with an exit code of `0` (zero).

There are two ways to "exit 0" when robot completes with a failed test:

1. Explicitly call the `exit` in the script that runs your tests.
2. Use the pybot option `--nostatusrc`

More information about robot framework return codes is covered in the [Return Codes](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#return-codes) section of the robot framework user guide.

### Using the exit command

`exit` is a command you can put into a script to force a specific status code. This command behaves the same both on unix and non-unix systems. It takes one argument (such as `0`) and exits the enclosing script with the given value as the exit code.

When you configure jenkins, you are creating a batch script (window) or shell script (non-windows) that contains one or more commands. You can add `exit 0` as the last command to force this script to "exit 0".

For example, you can configure your jenkins job to look like this:

```
pybot mytests.robot
exit 0
```

In this case, that last line will tell jenkins that the script exited cleanly without errors. The robot plugin for jenkins will then look at the output file (output.xml) to determine whether the build succeeded or failed.

### Using the command line option --nostatusrc

Beginning with robot version 2.5.7 you can use the command line option `--nostatusrc`, which causes robot to always "exit 0" no matter how many tests failed. You can include this option in your jenkins job like so:

```
pybot --nostatusrc mytests.robot
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem as OP and your answer works for me as well. I'm using pabot instead of pybot but fortunately pabot supports the same command line arguments as pybot.

Comment: I'm also running Robot through jenkins to test some features. When a robot test fails, also its jenkins build. I would like to mark a build as "unstable" rather than failed for some errors (such as "no network" because it's more of infrastructure problem rather than a BUG of the code, that cause the test to fail). I managed to wrap the jenkins job with try-catch, and raise special error from a python module (for example I raised an error with exit code == 3), but when pybot fails its exit code is still 1. Is there a way tell robot to propagate the exit code? @Bryan-Oakley

Comment: An explicit `exit 0` at the end of your script is rarely useful. Then the shell will exit with whatever exit code the last external commande in the script returned. For a production script, you often want the shell to exit with an error for *any* unhandled error from an external commanl. `set -e` at the beginning of your script does this - but don't do that blindly; this is a tough beast to tame if you haven't tried it before.

Comment: @tripleee: I agree it's rarely useful, but the OP was specifically asking how to force an exit with a zero exit code. This is one of those rare cases when it is useful to ignore the status of the last command and force an exit code of zero.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking more of new vistors than the original OP.